# Remove alias to string text

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js

please help me,

I have a string that corresponds to a SQL query;

```
let string = `SPMAMA.DOCUMENTO AS DOCUMENTO_MAMA,        
    NVL(SPMAMA.CARNETSALUS,SPMAMA_N.CARNETSALUS) AS CARNETSALUS_MAMA,
    NVL(SPMAMA.NOMBRE1 || ' ' || SPMAMA.NOMBRE2 || ' ' || SPMAMA.APELLIDO1 || ' ' || SPMAMA.APELLIDO2, 
    SPMAMA_N.NOMBRE1 || ' ' || SPMAMA_N.NOMBRE2 || ' ' || SPMAMA_N.APELLIDO1 || ' ' || SPMAMA_N.APELLIDO2) AS NOMBRE_MAMA`;
```

and I want to remove the alias "AS NAME_ALIAS". Something like this:

```
let strWithoutAlias = `SPMAMA.DOCUMENTO,        
    NVL(SPMAMA.CARNETSALUS,SPMAMA_N.CARNETSALUS),
    NVL(SPMAMA.NOMBRE1 || ' ' || SPMAMA.NOMBRE2 || ' ' || SPMAMA.APELLIDO1 || ' ' || SPMAMA.APELLIDO2, 
    SPMAMA_N.NOMBRE1 || ' ' || SPMAMA_N.NOMBRE2 || ' ' || SPMAMA_N.APELLIDO1 || ' ' || SPMAMA_N.APELLIDO2)`;
```

I don't know how to use split and slice to do this, as I think it would be a combination of both.

This is my silly code;

```
let strngSplit = `SPMAMA.DOCUMENTO AS DOCUMENTO_MAMA,        
NVL(SPMAMA.CARNETSALUS,SPMAMA_N.CARNETSALUS) AS CARNETSALUS_MAMA,
NVL(SPMAMA.NOMBRE1 || ' ' || SPMAMA.NOMBRE2 || ' ' || SPMAMA.APELLIDO1 || ' ' || SPMAMA.APELLIDO2, 
SPMAMA_N.NOMBRE1 || ' ' || SPMAMA_N.NOMBRE2 || ' ' || SPMAMA_N.APELLIDO1 || ' ' || SPMAMA_N.APELLIDO2) AS NOMBRE_MAMA`.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, '').split('AS')
```

Comment: Do you want to remove AS CARNETSALUS_MAMA and AS NOMBRE_MAMA both parts?

Comment: Smells like it would be simpler to use Regex for that, but, depending on what you actually intend to do, you may need something more complex. Having said that, why do you need to do the replacement? Maybe it could be a X-Y issue?

Comment: @SelakaN yes sr, thank for you help,  " AS DOCUMENTO_MAMA", " AS CARNETSALUS_MAMA" and "  AS NOMBRE_MAMA",  from " AS... " to next comma (,).

Comment: I have provided an answer check if its okay @AlJw

Comment: Wouldn't a simple `input.replace('AS CARNETSALUS_MAMA', '')` suffice?

Comment: @AlJw I have added an answer based on my assumption it's correct. If you need more additions to that answer its a matter of adding it to the array of replacements what you want to remove.

Comment: what if the aliases are dynamic and you have to replace a bunch of these queries and you don't know what the aliases are? you are all assuming that he wants to replace this 1 query and hard code it

Comment: Also, things like inner selects, derived tables, string constants and so on can break naive solutions. Again, it all depends on how this code is supposed to be used and how "freeform" the original SQL can be. Again, I would ask: what is the context where this will be used?

Comment: @AlJw thanks for the accepting, mate. you are welcome. i've upvoted your question so you could now upvote my answer (the arrow up), thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a regex to remove all aliases:

/\s+ - white spaces before AS
as - AS
\s+ - white spaces after AS
[^\s,]+ - alias, means anything but white spaces and a comma
/ig - case insensitive + all occurences

```js
const input = `SPMAMA.DOCUMENTO AS DOCUMENTO_MAMA,        
    NVL(SPMAMA.CARNETSALUS,SPMAMA_N.CARNETSALUS) AS CARNETSALUS_MAMA,
    NVL(SPMAMA.NOMBRE1 || ' ' || SPMAMA.NOMBRE2 || ' ' || SPMAMA.APELLIDO1 || ' ' || SPMAMA.APELLIDO2, 
    SPMAMA_N.NOMBRE1 || ' ' || SPMAMA_N.NOMBRE2 || ' ' || SPMAMA_N.APELLIDO1 || ' ' || SPMAMA_N.APELLIDO2) AS NOMBRE_MAMA`;

const replaced = input.replace(/\s+as\s+[^\s,]+/ig, '');

console.log(replaced);
```

Comment: Caveat: This will work okay as long as the SQL is in this simple format. More complex SQL will break for various reasons, like inner selects, string constants and so on.

Answer (score -1):

**As of my understanding, you don't need a regex for this. You can directly use the string `replace()` function and proceed ahead to remove the specified blocks of string from your original string.**

Refer the below code for reference:

```js
const input = `SPMAMA.DOCUMENTO AS DOCUMENTO_MAMA,        
    NVL(SPMAMA.CARNETSALUS,SPMAMA_N.CARNETSALUS) AS CARNETSALUS_MAMA,
    NVL(SPMAMA.NOMBRE1 || ' ' || SPMAMA.NOMBRE2 || ' ' || SPMAMA.APELLIDO1 || ' ' || SPMAMA.APELLIDO2, 
    SPMAMA_N.NOMBRE1 || ' ' || SPMAMA_N.NOMBRE2 || ' ' || SPMAMA_N.APELLIDO1 || ' ' || SPMAMA_N.APELLIDO2) AS NOMBRE_MAMA`;

function replaceString(inputString) {
  const replacements = [
    'AS DOCUMENTO_MAMA',
    'AS CARNETSALUS_MAMA',
    'AS NOMBRE_MAMA'
  ];

  let output = inputString;
  replacements.forEach(replacement => {
    output = output.replace(replacement, '');
  });

  return output;
}

console.log(replaceString(input));
```

Answer (score -1):

This work for me;

```
let GROUPBY_CAMPOS = TODOS_CAMPOS.map((e)=> {
            
            e = e.replace(' AS DOCUMENTO_MAMA', '')
            e = e.replace(' AS CARNETSALUS_MAMA', '')
            e = e.replace(' AS NOMBRE_MAMA', '')

            return e.split(' AS ')[0]
        })
```